# Lighthouse CLI - site with authentication

Tags: lighthouse

I'm trying to perform audit using Lighthouse CLI. My site requires authentication. How can I get Lighthouse CLI to analyse my site? Can I supply login credentials?

Also the CLI seems to be broken and/or not comply to documentation.

```
$ npm install -g lighthouse
$ lighthouse --help

C:\Users\kermit\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.1\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\lib\url-shim.js:36
class URLShim extends URL {
                      ^

ReferenceError: URL is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kermit\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.1\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\lib\url-shim.js:36:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kazuy\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.1\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\lib\network-request.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're using Node >= 10. URL got added at Node v10 (https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_url)

Answer (score 0):

Please Upgrade Node and apply single or double quote on URL like below with L-CLI

```
lighthouse 'https://google.com' --port=9222
```

For the authenticated page, you have two below options

```
1. use --extra-headers={cookies}
2. use --port=9222 //port is debug port
```